# Grep partial match (numerical) without any control over search string

Tags: bash, grep

My grep string/pattern will always contain at least one number and one space (this will never change), I'd like a match if there's a numerical match is this possible without changing the string? I've got full control of the grep arguments, but no control over the string or file content. Let's say I'm only interested in number matches and I have the following example:

```
cat example.txt
1 partridge in a pear tree
2 turtle doves
3 french hens

grep "1 french hens" example.txt
```

Obviously this will never match, is there arguments I can pass to make it match the first line (number match only) without changing the string? As I've said, I have full control over the grep arguments, but no control over any content. I know other tools are viable options (sed, awk, perl, cut), but I'd like to avoid overcomplicating this.

Comment: `grep "\b$(grep -o '[0-9]*' <<< "1 french hens")\b" example.txt` / `grep "\b$(tr -cd 0-9 <<< "1 french hens")\b" example.txt`

Comment: That's pretty cool, embedded grep - nice. Both approaches work and are pretty simple :D

Comment: They'll fail if there's more than one number, but you may be able to tweak the inner grep to match only the one you want.